# coneVolume Method returning zero

Tags: java, methods

I can't seem to figure out why my coneVolume method is returning zero when all of my other methods are working properly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P56old{
public static double sphereVolume(double r){
    double sphereVolume = (4/3)*(Math.PI)*(Math.pow(r, 3));
    return sphereVolume;
}
public static double sphereSurface(double r){
    double sphereSurface = 4 * (Math.PI) * Math.pow(r, 2);
    return sphereSurface;
}
public static double cylinderVolume(double r, double h){
    double cylinderVolume = (Math.PI) * (Math.pow(r, 2)) * h;
    return cylinderVolume;
}
public static double cylinderSurface(double r, double h){
    double cylinderSurface = 2 * (Math.PI) * (Math.pow(r, 2)) + 2 * Math.PI * r * h;
    return cylinderSurface;
}
public static double coneVolume(double r, double h){
    double coneVolume = (1/3) * Math.PI * (Math.pow(r,2)) * h;
    return coneVolume;
}
public static double coneSurface(double r, double h){
    double s = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r,2) + Math.pow(h, 2));
    double coneSurface = Math.PI * Math.pow(r,2) + Math.PI * r * s;
    return coneSurface;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please give the radius: ");
    double r = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Please give the height: ");
    double h = in.nextDouble();

    double coneVolume = coneVolume(r,h);
    double sphereVolume = sphereVolume(r);
    double sphereSurface = sphereSurface(r);
    double cylinderVolume = cylinderVolume(r,h);
    double cylinderSurface = cylinderSurface(r,h);
    double coneSurface = coneSurface(r,h);

    System.out.println("The Sphere Volume is " + sphereVolume);
    System.out.println("The Sphere Surface is " + sphereSurface);
    System.out.println("The Cylinder volume is " + cylinderVolume);
    System.out.println("The Cylinder Surface is " + cylinderSurface);
    System.out.println("The Cone Volume is " + coneVolume);
    System.out.println("The Cone Surface is " + coneSurface);
}
}
```

I'd appreciate any insight on the matter, and any critique is appreciated. I think it may have to do with all the public classes and maybe another method is affecting the coneVolume method but I just don't know enough about methods at the moment to fix the issue at hand.

Comment: From the answers below, your `sphereVolume()` method is also giving the incorrect value and needs to be changed similarly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do 1/3, it does integer division, resulting in 0 (the remainder is 1). Multiplying by 0 gives 0. Do 1.0/3.0 instead, and it will correctly compute an approximation to one third.

Comment: Wow, didn't even think it'd be that. Thanks!